# Trying to use Raft consensus in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.1 but getting SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- no Raft leader error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm currently working on my final year project and I need help concerning Raft.

I'm building a network with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.1 using 'Building your first network' tutorial and I want to manually generate the artifacts, channel, joining the channel... I chose Raft as the consensus algorithm. But I'm getting an error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- no Raft leader
```

Here is my code:[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlzBx.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem in the *start the network* session.
For the docker-compose, you need to add 1 more file.
the problem is your raft script is not being called at *start the network* session

instead of `docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d`

try to put

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-etcdraft2.yaml up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 1.4.1, you should probably use Raft rather than Kafka for the orderer consensus mechanism.

To use Raft, you should be able to run:

`./byfn.sh up -o etcdraft`

If you must / really want to use Kafka:

`./byfn.sh up -o kafka`

Comment: But I want to run the commands myself. I'm entering to following command: 
../bin/configtxgen -profile SampleDevModeKafka -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
but later when adding the channel I'm getting an error. Even with Raft. Should I change something in yaml files?

Comment: to know whether you should change something provide us with the relevant code snippets

Comment: Ok I updated my question and added the code. @kajuken

Comment: can you please add to the question, the logs of the orderer container? 
also - keep in mind that it takes a few seconds for the orderer to stabilize after it launches.